# xpath for a content text from node

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

im doing web scraping for first time using scrapy trying to get some prices from a web site. The thing is that i don't know how to get it because is inside the node content, first time with xpath so i'm little confuse. Let my give the example:

```
<span class="list d-block">
            <span class="value" content="1250">
                <span class="sr-only">
                    Precio reducido de
                </span> 
                <span class="price-original">
                        <span class="">
                            $1.250
                        </span>
                        (Normal)
                    
                </span>
                <span class="sr-only">
                    (Oferta)
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
```

I need to get the content, in this case "1250" in this case from @class= "value".

Any help will be great!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: .//span[@class="list d-block"]/span/@content]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to get **content** attribute value. here is the XPath:

```py
'//span[@class="<value>"]/@content'
```

Comment: I need to use "list d-block", so i try this: './/span[@class="list d-block"]/span[@class="value"]/@content]' but scrapy have an error: ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in .//span[@class="list d-block"]/span[@class="value"]/@content]

Comment: I think you have an extra **]** at the end of expression try '//span[@class="list d-block"]/span[@class="value"]/@content'

Answer (score 0):

On the xml that you posted this xpath should work:

```
string(//span[@class='value']/@content)
```

Please find [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/xpath-tutorial/topics/xpath-tutorial.html) tutorial for details on xpath.

Comment: That is correct, i can get "$1.250" that is almost the number, but my problem is that i have a not-regular code and the only patern that im sure, is that @content have the number that i need.   <span class="value" content="1250">

Comment: Why did you used "string"?

Comment: i have no xpath to test here, but if both return the same you can omit that